# Woocommerce remove zoom class from images

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook

How can I remove the zoom class from the images in woocommerce without actually going in php files and deleting the class manually? Like with hooks?

I found the filter for it

`apply_filters(  'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf(  '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image  ), $post->ID  );`

But I don't know how to override this? The zoom is quite annoying here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make an adjustment via filter. This is the same approach for any kind of filter you see in WordPress, you send back the value you want to use instead. I think I wrote a pretty good article about [WordPress filters](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/455/wordpress-filters-fundamentals/) if you want to try to read more.

But to answer your question you could do the following, which would keep the image link intact, but remove the zoom class:

```
function so_26609604_single_product_image_html( $html, $post_id ){
    $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
    $image_link  = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'shop_single', array( 'title' => $image_title ) );
    $html = sprintf(  '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image" title="%s">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image  );

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 'so_26609604_single_product_image_html', 10, 2 );
```

Or you could remove the link entirely and only display an image:

```
function so_26609604_single_product_image_html_alt( $html, $post_id ){
    $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'shop_single', array( 'title' => $image_title ) );
    return $image;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 'so_26609604_single_product_image_html_alt', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you! I'll read the article, it will come in useful later on :)

Comment: Btw, how do I find the appropriate filter to hook to? there are tons of them in woocommerce...

Comment: It just depends on what you are trying to change. I usually use Sublime Text 3 to search through all of WooCommerce files and look for html markup that is near to what I am looking to change. Anywhere you see `apply_filters()` you can hook into that.